# look for inner array ID ,sort it and loop outer array with the sorted ID

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have below code and there is reviewoutocme.ID which is unique identifier. how ever, We do not receive this in order. but I would like to sort all the requests in order based on this ID.

i.e. I want to look for reviewoutocme.ID and  when  reviewoutocme.ID=1, then loop RequestDetailsType Request first and so on.. 
how can I do that?
can we do something like that?

```
  IList< ServiceReference2.service> serviceList = new List< ServiceReference2.service>();
 foreach (RequestDetailsType Request in PatientRequest.Request.RequestDetailsList)
                    {
                        if (Request.ReviewOutcomes != null && Request.ReviewOutcomes .Length > 0)
                        {

                            foreach (ReviewOutcomeType reviewoutocme in Request.ReviewOutcomes)
                            {
                                var status = reviewoutocme.status.Value;
                               var dateofservice = reviewoutocme.fromDate;
                                ServiceReference2.service service = new ServiceReference2.service();
                             service.sequence=reviewoutocme.ID;
                                service.InitialReferralTemplate = Request.initialRequestFlag;
                                service.TotalUnits = Convert.ToInt32(Request.units);
                                service.DateOfService = dateofservice;
                                service.Status = status;
                                service.Sequence = Convert.ToInt32(Request.requestItemDetailSequence);
                                service.ServiceCategory = "REV";
                                serviceList.Add(service);


                            }
                        }
                        }
```

Comment: GroupBy + OrderBy

Comment: I am new to c# and do not know how to do that.. any syntax?

Answer (score 1):

modify you code above as

```
IList< ServiceReference2.service> serviceList = new List< ServiceReference2.service>();

var lstSortedRequest = PatientRequest.Request.RequestDetailsList.OrderBy(x => x.ReviewOutcomes.Select(y => y.ReviewOutcomeType.Id)).ThenBy(x => x.RequestDetailType).ToList();

foreach (var Request in lstSortedRequest)
{
    //process the request as you do in your question.
}
```

default ordering sequence is Ascending.

Comment: how do I define lstToSort.OrderBy(x => x.Id) before RequestDetailsType Request looping?

Comment: @chits I have updated my answer. Hope that solves your query

Comment: var lstSortedRequest = PatientRequest.Request.RequestDetailsList.OrderBy(x => x.ReviewOutcomes.OrderBy(y=>y.ID)). ToList(); RequestDetailsList has ReviewOutcomes and that has ID. I cannot give ReviewOutcomeType.Id somwhow

Comment: @chits Please check now if i am close to what you want.

Comment: thank you for your help! but it seems like I am getting the error

Comment: error is "at least one object must implement icomparable". I am totally new to programming and have no idea about these errors.

Comment: i got it working with var lstSortedRequest = patientRequest.Request.RequestDetailsList.Select(x => x.ReviewOutcomes.OrderBy(y=>y.ID)).ToArray();  but if I have 5 Id's , then   it is looping 15 times.. lol. Basically, I can have multiple requests and each request can have multiple details. In my scenario, I have 3 requests and 5 details(2 details for 1st request,2 details for 2nd request  and 1 detail for 3rd request). And each detail is unique with ID. When I try to loop request with this ID, the 3 requests are looping 5 times which results in 15 records.

Answer (score 0):

My rep is too low to comment.

Try:

```
var sortedList = reviewoutocme.OrderBy(x => x.ID).ToList();
```

Comment: c# methods always start with capital (I.E. ToList())

Comment: I can do this inside reviewoutocme. but I would like to check if my ID is 1 before I start looping RequestDetailsType Request. So I have to look for ID, when it is in 1 then take that first.

Comment: I would extract everything in your loop, run result from the below query,  and then loop through the list. So:

    `var result = Request.ReviewOutcomes.First(s => s.ID == 1);`  
    `ExtractedMethod(result, serviceList);`  
    `foreach (ReviewOutcomeType reviewoutocme in Request.ReviewOutcomes)`  
                           ` {`  
                               `if (reviewoutocme.ID == 1)`  
                                   `continue;`  
                                `ExtractedMethod(reviewoutocme, serviceList);`  
                            `}`